# Is there a performance overhead when manually serializing gRPC request & response objects

Tags: node.js, nestjs, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-node

My goal is to send and receive data to/from a NodeJS microservice. The problem is that both my request and response objects are quite dynamic - fields with `string | number` union types, maps with a set of predefined keys and then some dynamic ones. Converting this into `protobuf3` structures proves to be an uneasy task and furthermore, `google.protobuf.Any` seems to not be available for `@grpc/proto-loader`, so I can't utilize it.

However if I send a `JSON.stringify`-ed payload and then `JSON.parse` it, there seems to be no problem, as my proto message includes a single `string` field with the manually serialized payload.

Is this approach acceptable? I know there must be some overhead in the manual serialization but it does seem to get the job done. Am I missing something?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to determine whether you would be using any less JSON parsing if you were able to use another approach. From what I understand of your goal, this seems unlikely (i.e. your JSON parsing needs are probably similiar either way).

One thing to bear in mind is that you're creating a hierarchy of schemas in different definition languages: a protobuf schema and (multiple) JSON schemas. One benefit of protobufs is that messages are typed. When a message is overwhelmingly embedded JSON, it is effectively a string type which loses a benefit of protobufs.

Again, from what I understand from your question, I'd question whether protobufs|gRPC are the most appropriate technologies for you. Although it's uncommon, you **can** use gRPC without protobuf.  But, RPC (not just gRPC) benefit from typing and, because you're almost shipping strings, your methods become `Foo(string) string` and RPC (gRPC) seem overwrought.